# How Can I Achieve this Using LINQ?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

The best way I can describe what I'm trying to do is "Nested DistinctBy".

Let's say I have a collection of objects.  Each object contains a collection of nicknames.

```
class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Priority { get; set; }
    public string[] Nicknames { get; set; }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var People = new List<Person>
        {
            new Person { Name = "Steve", Priority = 4, Nicknames = new string[] { "Stevo", "Lefty", "Slim" }},
            new Person { Name = "Karen", Priority = 6, Nicknames = new string[] { "Kary", "Birdie", "Snookie" }},
            new Person { Name = "Molly", Priority = 3, Nicknames = new string[] { "Mol", "Lefty", "Dixie" }},
            new Person { Name = "Greg", Priority = 5, Nicknames = new string[] { "G-man", "Chubs", "Skippy" }}
        };      
    }
}
```

I want to select all Persons but make sure nobody selected shares a nickname with another. Molly and Steve both share the nickname 'Lefty' so I want to filter one of them out.  Only the one with highest priority should be included. If there is a highest priority tie between 2 or more then just pick the first one of them. So in this example I would want an IEnumerable of all people except Steve.

EDIT: Here's another example using music album instead of person, might make more sense.

```
class Album
{
   string Name {get; set;}
   int Priority {get;set;}
   string[] Aliases {get; set;}
{

class Program
{
var NeilYoungAlbums = new List<Album>
    {
        new Person{ Name = "Harvest (Remastered)", Priority = 4, Aliases = new string[] { "Harvest (1972)", "Harvest (2012)"}},
        new Person{ Name = "On The Beach", Priority = 6, Aliases = new string[] { "The Beach Album", "On The Beach (1974)"}},
        new Person{ Name = "Harvest", Priority = 3, Aliases = new string[] { "Harvest (1972)"}},
        new Person{ Name = "Freedom", Priority = 5, Aliases = new string[] { "Freedom (1989)"}}
    };
}
```

The idea here is we want to show his discography but we want to skip quasi-duplicates.

Comment: Do lower numbers mean a "higher" priority in this example?

Comment: @samgak Steve has a priority of `4` and Molly has a priority of `3`. Both share *Lefty* as nickname and Molly is selected over Steve, so I would assume lower numbers mean higher priority.

Comment: What if two persons have the same priority and share a common nickname?

Comment: Suppose person 1 and person 2 share a nickname, so person 2 is excluded. Then suppose person 2 and person 3 share a nickname, should person 3 be excluded even if they don't share a nickname with person 1?

Comment: @samgak Since person 2 was already excluded, there is no collision between persons 2 and 3, so person 3 stays.

Comment: @BasilKosovan Then Greg would be filtered out because his priority is low.  The idea is if you took the final result and selected all nicknames, there would be no duplicates.  I should have done example more applicable not a Person.

Comment: @Steve Then just pick one doesn't matter which.

Comment: The Person example was a poor choice. Think of it this way.  If two people share a common nickname, they're really the same person. We don't want duplicate people selected. In this example Molly and Steve are secretly the same person, we only want one.

Comment: @SeanO'Neil if that's the case, than the whole architecture is wrong.

Comment: @AgentFire you don't have anything close to enough information to form that opinion.

Comment: @SeanO'Neil I have enough. I see that for each record you have an array of aliases. I also understand that records are kept in databases. So either you store everything in memory, which is bad design, or you load all the data to your C# program from the DB and run your table-logic there, instead of doing it inside the database, which again, is a bad practice. The last option is that you processing some kind of a web request, where the server does not have any state and has to work with the data itis provided from some API client, in which case...

Comment: ...I can hardly imagine a situation where you would need to exclude some aliases-based records.

Comment: The data storage is a NoSQL solution, and for very good reasons. Your "last option" is kind of on the right track though it's not a web request. I'm sorry you can hardly imagine the use case. I added a second example above which may help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A LINQ-only solution

```
var dupeQuery = people
    .SelectMany( p => p.Nicknames.Select( n => new { Nickname = n, Person = p } ) )
    .ToLookup( e => e.Nickname, e => e.Person )
    .SelectMany( e => e.OrderBy( p => p.Priority ).Skip( 1 ) );

var result = people.Except( dupeQuery ).ToList();
```

See [.net fiddle sample](https://dotnetfiddle.net/A58J0k)

Comment: Dang, you beat me to it, was just about to post an answer. And don't worry :)

Comment: @Caramiriel sorry ;o)

Answer (score 5):

I would solve this using a custom [`IEqualityComparer<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.iequalitycomparer-1):

```
class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Priority { get; set; }

    public string[] Nicknames { get; set; }
}

class PersonEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Person>
{
    public bool Equals(Person x, Person y)
    {
        if (x == null || y == null) return false;

        return x.Nicknames.Any(i => y.Nicknames.Any(j => i == j));
    }

    // This is bad for performance, but if performance is not a
    // concern, it allows for more readability of the LINQ below
    // However you should check the Edit, if you want a truely 
    // LINQ only solution, without a wonky implementation of GetHashCode
    public int GetHashCode(Person obj) => 0;
}

// ...

var people = new List<Person>
{
    new Person { Name = "Steve", Priority = 4, Nicknames = new[] { "Stevo", "Lefty", "Slim" } },
    new Person { Name = "Karen", Priority = 6, Nicknames = new[] { "Kary", "Birdie", "Snookie" } },
    new Person { Name = "Molly", Priority = 3, Nicknames = new[] { "Mol", "Lefty", "Dixie" } },
    new Person { Name = "Greg", Priority = 5, Nicknames = new[] { "G-man", "Chubs", "Skippy" } }
};

var distinctPeople = people.OrderBy(i => i.Priority).Distinct(new PersonEqualityComparer());
```

**EDIT:**

Just for completeness, this could be a possible LINQ only approach:

```
var personNicknames = people.SelectMany(person => person.Nicknames
        .Select(nickname => new { person, nickname }));
var groupedPersonNicknames = personNicknames.GroupBy(i => i.nickname);
var duplicatePeople = groupedPersonNicknames.SelectMany(i => 
        i.OrderBy(j => j.person.Priority)
        .Skip(1).Select(j => j.person)
    );

var distinctPeople = people.Except(duplicatePeople);
```

Answer (score 2):

This works once, then you have to clear the set. Or store the results in a collection.

```
var uniqueNicknames = new HashSet<string>();

IEnumerable<Person> uniquePeople = people
    .OrderBy(T => T.Priority) // ByDescending?
    .Where(T => T.Nicknames.All(N => !uniqueNicknames.Contains(N)))
    .Where(T => T.Nicknames.All(N => uniqueNicknames.Add(N)));
```

Comment: uniqueNicknames can init by SelectMany, GroupBy, Having

Comment: the first where doesn't seem to be needed as it is checking empty set

Comment: IMHO I wouldn't want `.Where(T => T.Nicknames.All(N => uniqueNicknames.Add(N)))` to appear in any of my code.

Comment: @TobiasTengler IMHO it's much better code than having `IEqualityComparer<T>` implementation of `GetHashCode` returning constant value as in your code (`public int GetHashCode(Person obj) => 0;`).

Comment: @IvanStoev that's of course debateable. Performing an add operation from a `Where` statement, just seems ridiculous. Imagine someone looking at this code without context. He sees a `Where` statement and correctly assumes it performs a filter operation. This is an unnecessary side effect.

Comment: @TobiasTengler The problem is not the `Add` operation - as you can see, the [implementation](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,4ab583c7d8e84d6d,references) of the `Distinct` method also uses `Add`. The problem is (and I agree) that the code has side effect and can be run correctly only once, but the author specifically mentioned that.

Comment: @IvanStoev Just to clear this up, I didn't meant that him performing an add operation for this task is wrong. I'm bugged by where (no pun intended) the operation happens. I hate quoting the docs to make a point, but the `Where` documentation reads: [Filters a sequence of values based on a predicate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where). Performing an add operation in the context of a `Where` statement is just not how it was intended to use. But my answer/code isn't perfect either, so I will stop complaining now.